# Rails: Unknown action The action 'update' could not be found for OtherController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I began learning rails several days before. Here I have a project setup. I generate a new controller named "my", the method in it is called "update". 
The controller is like:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @person = Entry.last
    @fname = @person.first_name
    @lname = @person.last_name
    @person.update_attributes({:address => params[:st_name],
                               :salary => params[:salary], :loan => params[:loan],
                               :loan_reason => params[:reason]})
    if !@person.address.nil? then render "show" end
  end
end
```

In my form of the HTML, codes are:

```
    <%= form_tag**({:controller => "my", :action => "update"} , :method => 'get')** do %> 
 <p> Address:   <%= text_field_tag 'st_name', @address %>
   <p> Salary:
    <%= text_field_tag 'salary', @salary %>
       <p> Loan Amount:
    <%= text_field_tag 'loan', @loan %>
       <p> Loan Reason:
    <%= text_field_tag 'reason', @loan_reason %>
   <%= submit_tag 'send' %>
<% end %>
```

Must have something wrong with the 1 line.

When I run the project, it says:
Unknown action
The action 'update' could not be found for OtherController

Can anyone give me some advece?  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

should be `:url => {:controller => "my", :action => "update"}`

Comment: Thanks, finnally i found that i should generate the controller by commands.  :)